# OpenCL create command queue

Tags: c, opencl

I tried to create command queue in OpenCL on device, but result is CL_INVALID_VALUE. Example of creating queue:

`cl_uint maxQueueSize = 450000;
    cl_queue_properties proprt[] = { CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT,  CL_QUEUE_SIZE, maxQueueSize, 0 };
    gpuControlData->cmdQueue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(gpuControlData->context, gpuControlData->device, proprt, &err);`

If I write on create command queue 0 instead of proprt, everything are working, but it is In-Order and command queue is on Host device. If I use only =CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, program create command queue without problem, but the queue is on host device.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I trying to get number of command queues on device. But respond of device is 0. But this value must be minimal 1. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.1.pdf#page=76

Comment: I use cl_uint result; clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_ON_DEVICE_QUEUES, sizeof(cl_uint), &result, nullptr);, but device result is 0. So it is wrong device or wronh wrtiting parameters?

Comment: why don't you query device name?

Comment: I don´t write all query what I write on program, and device name is not nessesary for getting value of max device queue

Comment: Did you find a solution?